# Android-приложение. Информация о закрытии приложения

Tags: java, android, защита

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть 2 приложения .Первое приложение открывает второе через pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.ofret.tbs")
Как я могу узнать когда закрывается второе приложение с первого, и если оно закрыто то возобновлять?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Шлите при закрытии приложения интент, другим приложением ловите его

Comment: Проблема в том что второе приложение не мое

Comment: Без root никак не сделать

Answer (score 0):

Можно узнать запущено или нет по имени пакета...

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();
```

Когда работает Ваше приложение, другое не закроется в нормальной ситуации, а в своем на onResume проверить, запущенное ли второе... Если специально во втором приложении не запускается ваше, то ничего сделать не получится...